# Queuing with Node/ExpressJS

Tags: node.js

I have a requirement where UI(built in React) initiates a request to backend for one record of the DB. The backend then fetch one record from the DB and serve it to the request. The record that is served before to the first user should not be server to other UI requests. How can I handle this in Node/Express without sending the same record to multiple users?

I want to try blocking operations in nodejs but wanted to see if there is any better approach

Comment: Best way is to mark the record in your db. If the record is served, mark it by updating that record in the db and do not serve it in the next request.